# Count 1 or 0, whether text in var1 observations contain at least 1 chr str in a list element, if list element label matches var2

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a dataframe in R `mydf`.

```
mydf<-data.frame(
  last_name <- c("Jay", "Kelly", "Mark", "Lisa", "Jay", "Kelly", "Mark", "Lisa", "Lisa", "Lisa", "Kelly", "Kelly"),
  first_name <- c("Lee", "Ty", "Ben", "Joe", "Lee", "Ty", "Ben", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Ty", "Ty"),
  state_abbrevs <- c("KY", "UT", "OH", "IA", "KY", "UT", "OH", "IA", "IA", "IA", "UT", "UT"),
  tw_year <-c(1998, 2001, 2001, 2003, 1998, 2001, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2003, 2000, 2002),
  tw_month <-c(1, 3, 4, 5, 12, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1, 10),
  text <-c("Thanks to everyone in Orange County!", "Several cities and townships in the state are flooded", "New Mexico's communities are suffering",
         "Today is the LAST day to register", "Ohio Senator Jay is great", "I love UT and KY - both are awesome",
         "On Monday, the prez will release a statement", "Ohio Senator Jay is great", "The villages in Iowa are nice", 
         "The villages, cities and towns in iowa are nice", "Salt Late City is crazy this time of year", "I only drink S.Pellegrino"))
```

I also have a list of lists called `terms`

```
terms <- list(
  NH = c("New Hampshire", "NH", "Village", "Villages", "villages", "County", "county", "City", "cities"),
  IA = c("iowa", "Iowa", "IA", "Village", "Villages", "villages", "County", "county", "City", "cities"),
  KY = c("Kentucy", "KY", "ky", "Village", "Villages", "villages", "County", "county", "City", "cities"),
  OH = c("Ohio", "OH", "oh", "Village", "Villages", "villages", "County", "county", "City", "cities"))
```

I want to create a new dataset that provides a count of whether each observation in `mydf$text` contains at least one of the character strings in the list element (not sure if list element is the correct terminology?) but only if `mydf$state_abbrev` matches the corresponding element label for the list. For example, I only want to match the character strings of `mydf$text` if the  the the list label (either "NH", "IA", "KY", or "OH") matches the mydf$text observation's  corresponding `mydf$state_abbrev`.

After trying multiple variations of code that did not work, I have been fixated on the code below using `dplyr` - the thing is I've been trying to troubleshoot this for days, and I need a fresh pair of eyes.

```
library(dplyr)

df_count <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(state_abbrev = tolower(state_abbrev)) %>% # convert state abbreviations to lowercase
  mutate(terms = terms[[state_abbrev]]) %>% # match st_terms to state_abbrev
  group_by(last_name, first_name, tw_year, tw_month) %>% # group by desired variables
  summarize(terms_count = sum(str_detect(text, regex(paste(terms, collapse = "|"), ignore_case = TRUE)) %>% as.integer())) # count the number of matches for each group
```

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `state_abbrev = tolower(state_abbrev)`.
Caused by error in `tolower()`:
! object 'state_abbrev' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `state_abbrev = tolower(state_abbrev)`.
Caused by error in `tolower()`:
! object 'state_abbrev' not found
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% ...
  2. ├─dplyr::summarize(...)
  3. ├─dplyr::group_by(., last_name, first_name, tw_year, tw_month)
  4. ├─dplyr::mutate(., terms = terms[[state_abbrev]])
  5. ├─dplyr::mutate(., state_abbrev = tolower(state_abbrev))
  6. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., state_abbrev = tolower(state_abbrev))
  7. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
  8. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  9. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 10. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 11. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
 12. └─base::tolower(state_abbrev)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 3 hidden frames.
```

The new dataset should look something like this:

| last_name | first_name | state_abbrev | tw_month | tw_year | count_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jay | Lee | KY | 1 | 1998 | 2 |
| Jay | Lee | KY | 1 | 2000 | 0 |
| Lisa | Joe | IA | 5 | 2004 | 1 |
| Lisa | Joe | IA | 4 | 2003 | 0 |
| Lisa | Joe | IA | 3 | 2003 | 1 |

Comment: The variable in your data is `state_abbrevs` (with an `s` at the end), but your code uses `state_abbrev`.

Comment: Yes, I did that - thanks for pointing that out. This wasn't exactly the problem (just an error when I copying my code into stack overflow), but that's the first place I should look when troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I found a solution:

```
# Define the function to count matches in each text
count_matches <- function(text, terms_keywords) {
  sum(str_detect(text, regex(paste(terms_keywords, collapse = "|"), 
  ignore_case = TRUE)))
     }

# Create a new dataset with the required counts
tweet_count <- tweet_sen %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(count = count_matches(text, terms[[match(state_abbrevs, names(terms))]])) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 group_by(last_name, first_name, tw_year, tw_month) %>%
 summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
 ungroup()
```